# ruby http static web server with watch mode?

Tags: ruby, http, web, static, watch

Is there a ruby http server (like httpd) for static web sites with a watch mode that updates the browser?

Currently if the website is running in httpd I have to refresh the browser after file changes.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails has [ActionCable](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) which uses websockets to keep a browser up to date using a publish/subscribe method.

**Edit**: [Faye-websocket](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby) is a websocket implementation that doesn't require any framework, just a Rack-compliant web server.

Depending on your needs there may be pre-built application available. For example, if you want a dashboard with widgets that update live, you can use [Smashing](https://github.com/Smashing/smashing).

Comment: sorry - without going to ruby on rails.... I wanted something simple e.g. nodemon for JavaScript

Comment: Faye & Smashing are great recommendations but I don't see how they can be used from the terminal to serve up static html like httpd

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mark's answer, [`iodine`](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine) is a Ruby HTTP and Websocket server written in C.

It sports a basic static file service as well as native support for Websocket connections (using a websocket callback object).

The static file service doesn't even require a Ruby application. i.e.:

```
 $  iodine -www ./
```

Iodine also supports pub/sub (with or without Redis) out of the box, moving a lot of the workload out of the Ruby layer and into the C engine.

It's possible to run iodine in single threaded mode (due to it's evented design), though the current default will use as many threads and processes as there are cores on the machine (which prefers concurrency over performance).

When using Rails, iodine can be used instead of ActionCable by catching Websocket connections using middleware (either custom made or, for example, the [Plezi gem](http://www.plezi.io)).

I'm biased, being the author, but I think it's an easy solution to implement and my tests show that it's significantly more performant.

Comment: does it have a watch ability? So you don't need to refresh the browser?

Comment: @Ruegen - I'm not sure what you mean by "watcher". If you're referring to a Websocket that allows you to update realtime data without refreshing the page - yes, that's iodine's focus feature. Iodine also uses ETags for cache validation, so if you mean "watching for file charges", you could say that it does, but the browser still needs to reload the page in order to test for cache validation.

Comment: Guard for rails has a live-reload gem that allows me to have the browser auto update/refresh when I write a change to files. I'd like this in httpd (or some similar tool).

Comment: @Ruegen - sorry, iodine doesn't have a built in push functionality for file/folder changes. This isn't the cheapest task (it requires a Websocket connection for push or AJAX for polling by the client). However, this can be authored using iodine's Websocket API (to push updates) and iodine's epoll/kqueue gateway API (to listen to folder/file changes). This also requires a Javascript snippet to all the HTML pages you want to keep "hot". Than again, this is pretty much what [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) does, so you might as well just use it.

Comment: all good - thanks for looking into it anyway. I probably will use Guard until I find something all-in-one.